# how to batch process some certain action in blender?

Tags: modeling

I have over 100 objects in a blender file and need to do limited dissolve for each of them. is there a way to do once and the rest of them will redo the action automatically? Like press a "record" buttom, press "x", choose "limited dissolve", process done. click "top" buttom, and sellect rest of the objects I wanna do the samething to.

I know it's like a scripting things, but I know nothing about python..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is an [Action Recorder](https://github.com/InamuraJIN/ActionRecorder) add-on, thanks to InamuraJIN..

Here, if your 'Limited Dissolve' parameters are the same for all the objects, you could put them all into Edit Mode simultaneously, and execute the operator just once, for all of them?

Comment: Cool ! I'll try it out